# Question on axiom of construction

Tags: logic, set-theory

> C = {A:A is a class and A satisfies the property ¬(A ∈ A)}= {A : A ∈
>   A} which leads to Russell's paradox, since neither C $\notin$ C ⇔ C ∈ C is
>   both 
>    and absurd.

I don't get how this

> C $\notin$ C ⇔ C ∈ C

Was obtained from the original statement.

Here's the axiom of class construction:

> Axiom A2 (Axiom of class construction): Let $P(x)$ designate a
>   statement about $x$ which can be expressed entirely in terms of the
>   symbols $∈,∨,∧,¬,⇒,∀$,brackets and  variables $x, y, z, ..., A, B,
> > ...$ Then there exists a class $C$ which consists of all the elements
>   $x$ which satisfy $P(x)$.

Comment: It should read $C\in C\Leftrightarrow C\notin C$, right?

Comment: What source are you quoting, and are you sure you copied it correctly? Wasn't $\{A:A\in A\}$ supposed to be $\{A:A\notin A\}?$

Comment: By the way, the title of your question means nothing to me, because I have never heard of an "axiom of construction". What does that axiom say?

Comment: Maybe you meant "axiom of comprehension"?

Comment: Added all the missing stuff

Comment: It's not clear what is your axiomatic framework here. It seems almost as though you're working with NBG or KM, but maybe you're working with ZF or just naive set theory?

Comment: In the formal language of first-order set theory it is not possible to say "There exists a class $C$." When we write $C=\{x:P(x)\}$  we are merely creating an abbreviation. We write $x\in C$ in place of $P(x)$. In particular instances $P(x)$ can be very long.  It is quite another thing to write $\exists C\;\forall x\;(x\in C\iff P(x)\;).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $C\in C$ then it must satisfy the property behind the colon in the class definition: $\neg(C\in C)$ also written as $C\notin C$, so we have
$$C\in C \implies C\notin C$$

If $C\notin C$ then it satisfies the property so it is an element of $C$. So we also have
$$C\notin C \implies C\in C$$
Combining them yields
$$C\in C \iff C\notin C$$

Comment: Regarding "If $C$ is an element of $C$"  , isn't C a set? If so, how is a set an element of itself?

Comment: In some set theories this is allowed. In ZFC it is not allowed by the axiom of regularity. Read the intro here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity

Comment: It doesn't matter whether $C$ is a set or a widget and it doesn't matter whether $\in$ means "belongs to" or "is shaved by". It is illogical to assert the existence of a widget that shaves all those and only those widgets that do not shave themselves.